# WatchKit App won't compile: "error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

There are several posts on this issue but none of the proposed solutions work in my case.  I am trying to integrate the WatchKit into a simple, sample app (I've tried a couple now) by following the instructions provided by Apple.  When I compile I get the following error message:

> "error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps. Verify
>   that the value of WKWatchKitApp in your WatchKit App's Info.plist is
>   set to YES."

I have successfully compiled and run the Apple Watch "Catalog" example so I know things are working from an iPhone to Watch perspective.  It seems like something is not right when I try to integrate with an existing app.
I have seen the posts here on this topic (e.g. [WatchKit app wont run on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426315/watchkit-app-wont-run-on-simulator)) but none of the fixes work in my case; the bundle IDs all appear to be correct. Note I am trying to compile and run on an iPhone 6 not on the simulator.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked Watchkit App info plist key `WKWatchKitApp`? is that true?

Comment: Checked that and WKWatchKitApp is set to YES

Answer (score 46):

This error occurred for me when I changed the bundle id of my main iOS App.
This is what I did in the project explorer

1. Under WatchApp --> plist

   `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier ==> Give the id of the iOS App (com.xxxx.appname)`
2. Under WatchApp Extension --> plist
   `NSExtension-->NSExtensionAttributes-->WKAppBundleIdentifier ==> Give the id of your watchkit app (eg: com.xxxx.appname.watchkitapp)`

this fixed the error for me.

Comment: Anyone who still gets the error after doing this should check out nmunjal's answer below. It solved it for me.

Comment: This answer still checks out as of Oct 2019. I discovered this when duplicating targets for a new bundle ID for the central app.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to write the bundles manually & couldn't use $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem on `XCode Version 10.2 (10E125)`, i realizes when i changed WatchkitApp Bundle identifier one key in watchkitapp extension did not changed and stayed as old bundle identifier.

the path to plist: /Users/.../YourXcodeProjectFolder/Project/YourWatchkitExtensionFolder/info.plist

the problem occurd here:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>WKAppBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.applecode.water.watchkit</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.watchkit</string>
</dict>
```

the key `WKAppBundleIdentifier` was made the problem, so i changed it by my self.

Comment: Changing the info.plist on both the extension and the app to match the identifier worked for me. I'm on 11..2.1 on xcode

Comment: i did same in 11.3.1 but issue still exists , any resolution ?

Answer (score 5):

I noticed this on Xcode version 8.2.1. Here is how I fixed it.

Go to "WatchKit App" -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Product Name

Change it so any string different from current string. Agreed that it is a bizarre solution as called in the link below.

Source: https://blogofpuneet.wordpress.com/2015/05/02/xcode-build-error-watchkit-extension-doesnt-contain-any-watchkit-apps-verify-that-the-value-of-wkwatchkitapp-in-your-watchkit-apps-info-plist-is-set-to-yes/

Comment: For crying out loud ... I've been stuck on the seemingly opposite "WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions" error all day, and this fixed that, too. I added "foo" to the end of the product name, then ran the app and it worked for the first time, then removed "foo" and it still works.

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1 its still giving me same error ? Any solution pls ?

Answer (score 4):

Main reasons to this error,

1 Incorrect watch app bundle id in watchkit extension plist file.

2. Missing dependancy of watchapp.app in watchkit extension target.

Apple document with catalag example may help
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Turns out this is a key article on configuring WatchKit apps (with lots of details, etc.).  One of my sample apps now works after lots of fiddling around and a second – more complicated app – still does not work and reports the same error.  But at least I have a working example now.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Below settings worked for me

- In Main App Info.plist

Bundle identifier:com.domain.WatchKit-table

- In Watchkit App Info.plist

WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier:com.domain.WatchKit-table

Bundle identifier:com.domain.WatchKit-table.**watchkitapp**

- WatchKit Extension Info.plist

NSExtension>NSExtensionAttributes>WKAppBundleIdentifier:**com.domain.WatchKit-table.watchkitapp**

Bundle identifier:com.domain.WatchKit-table.**watchkitapp.watchkitextension**

Note: my bundle id has * as the third component.
WatchKit-table is my project name

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this with xcode 10.0 after changing the build number.

Cleaning the build folder, closing xcode, and re-opening worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had problem with building of the extension library. In fact it was not built and I had two errors:
1. From linker about absense of the extension library.
2. From Xcode about "missing" NSExtensionPointIdentifier key.

Fix of linking error also fixed this message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xamarin and Visual Studio (on the PC).  I had this issue, but none of the fixes above worked.  Much like the XCode fix, however, restarting Visual Studio turned out to be the answer.  /sigh