# WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps. Xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, watchkit, watchos

I've deployed the app to the App Store several times with the Watch app embebed. However, since Xcode 7.x I am unable to archive the app (works fine for development).

> ValidateEmbeddedBinary DerivedData/App/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/PlugIns/App\ WatchKit\ Extension.appex
>       cd /Users/me/Development/App/iOS
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-embeddedBinaryValidationUtility /Users/me/Development/App/iOS/DerivedData/App/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App/PlugIns/App\ WatchKit\ Extension.appex -signing-cert 3120BEFCF28921F980E9AE4115E0EF0172C066EF -info-plist-path /Users/me/Development/App/iOS/DerivedData/App/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/Info.plist
>
> error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps. Verify that the value of WKWatchKitApp in your WatchKit App's Info.plist is set to YES.

I've tried the answers suggested in many others threads regarding this:

[Error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099239/error-watchkit-extension-doesnt-contain-any-watchkit-apps)

[WatchKit app wont run on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426315/watchkit-app-wont-run-on-simulator)

The Watch app it's still written using WatchOS1. Did I miss something? I'm super frustrated with this because I can't ship and I've spend so many hours in vain

**EDIT**

I've changed the app's deployment target to 8.2 from 7.0 and now it archives. Crazy.

However I would prefer not to drop iOS7 (represents ~10% of the users).

After archiving setting all the targets to 8.2 and set back 7.0 again in the app's target. Is not complaining again. Xcode, please, stop this madness!

Comment: In WatchKit extension's `info.plist` check if you have set the right value under `NSExtension` In `NSExtensionAttributes` against `WKAppBundleIdentifier`

Comment: In WatchKit App's `info.plist` check if you have set the right value against `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` and `Bundle identifier` should be like `com.exapmle.appname.watchkitapp`

Comment: yes, it's all set as this document says https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html (also I've deployed this to the app store several times)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @nemesis yes, it's in the edited part but don't hope to find any sense on it 
`After archiving setting all the targets to 8.2 and set back 7.0 again in the app's target. Is not complaining again. Xcode, please, stop this madness!`